# Sort vector of strings by characters from behind the strings

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe with a number of repetitive column names separated by a serial number. It looks something like this:

```
temp <- c("DTA_1", "DTA_2", "DTA_3", "OCI_1", "OCI_2", "OCI_3", "Time_1", "Time_2", "Time_3")
```

At the end it should look like this

```
temp <- c("DTA_1", "Time_1", "OCI_1", "DTA_2", "Time_2", "OCI_2", "DTA_3", "Time_3", "OCI_3")
```

I've started working on it and I came to this:

```
for(i in 1:length(tt)){
   paste(rev(strsplit(tt[i], "")[[1]]), collapse = "")
}
```

but then I realized I have to sort them after that and turn all the variables around again... It just seemed dumb and stupid.

Is there a better, more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Do you only want to sort them by the number or you also need that, for every number, the word is sorted alphabetically? (i ask since in the output example you put "Time" before "OCI")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the custom order of the strings by converting them to `factor` and specifying the order in the `levels`

```
temp[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", temp)),
            factor(gsub("_\\d+", "", temp), levels = c("DTA", "Time", "OCI")))]
#[1] "DTA_1"  "Time_1" "OCI_1"  "DTA_2"  "Time_2" "OCI_2"  "DTA_3"  "Time_3" "OCI_3"
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to read it to a 2 column data.frame by specifying the delimiter as `_`, `order` the columns and use that index for `order`ing the vector

```
temp[do.call(order, transform(read.table(text = temp, header = FALSE, 
    sep="_"), V1 = factor(V1, levels = c("DTA", "Time", "OCI")))[2:1])]
#[1] "DTA_1"  "Time_1" "OCI_1"  "DTA_2"  "Time_2" "OCI_2"  "DTA_3"  "Time_3" "OCI_3"
```

Or as @d.b mentioned in the comments, instead of converting to `factor`, use `match` and `order` based on that index

```
temp[with(read.table(text = temp, sep = "_"), order(V2, 
          match(V1, c("DTA", "Time", "OCI"))))]
#[1] "DTA_1"  "Time_1" "OCI_1"  "DTA_2"  "Time_2" "OCI_2"  "DTA_3"  "Time_3" "OCI_3"
```

---

Or an option in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
tibble(temp) %>% 
  separate(temp, into = c('t1', 't2'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(t2, fct_relevel(t1, c('DTA', 'Time', 'OCI'))) %>%
  unite(temp, t1, t2, sep="_") %>% 
  pull(temp)
#[1] "DTA_1"  "Time_1" "OCI_1"  "DTA_2"  "Time_2" "OCI_2"  "DTA_3"  "Time_3" "OCI_3"
```